# C++ and Python- checking type of PyObject fails

Tags: c++, python, pyobject

I'm a bit confused. I'm trying to do some C++ and Python integration, but it's less than straightforward. I'm not using Boost, because I couldn't get Boost::Python to compile properly. But that's another story.

Currently, here's what I'm doing in C++:

```
//set everything up
PyObject* py_main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* py_global_dict = PyModule_GetDict(py_main_module);
PyObject* py_local_dict = PyDict_New();
PyObject* py_return_value;

PyRun_SimpleString(data.c_str()); //runs Python code, which defines functions

//call a function defined by the python code
py_return_value = PyRun_String("test()", Py_single_input, py_global_dict, py_local_dict);

//attempt to check the type of the returned value
if(py_return_value != NULL) {
    //this is the problem: all of these print 0
    cout << PyList_Check(py_return_value) << endl;
    cout << PySet_Check(py_return_value) << endl;
    cout << PyFloat_Check(py_return_value) << endl;
} else {
    cout << "IT WAS NULL?!" << endl;
}
```

The Python program (input to the C++ program as the string named "data"):

```
def test():
    derp = 1.234
    #derp = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    #derp = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
    return derp
```

Now, the problem is that the type checks aren't working. They all return 0, regardless of whether the Python function is returning a float, a list, or a set. What am I doing wrong?

Bonus points if anyone can tell me why the call to PyRun_String prints the returned value in the console. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#Py_eval_input):

> `int Py_eval_input`
>
> The start symbol from the Python grammar for isolated expressions; for use with `Py_CompileString()`.
>
> `int Py_file_input`
>
> The start symbol from the Python grammar for sequences of statements as read from a file or other source; for use with
>   `Py_CompileString()`. This is the symbol to use when compiling
>   arbitrarily long Python source code.
>
> `int Py_single_input`
>
> The start symbol from the Python grammar for a single statement; for use with `Py_CompileString()`. This is the symbol used for the
>   interactive interpreter loop.

`Py_single_input` evaluates the string as a *statement*. Statements don't inherently return anything, so you'll get `None` back from `PyRun_String`. Use `Py_eval_input` instead to evaluate the string as an *expression* and get a result.

Comment: Thank you! That does indeed solve both of my problems.
What is the difference between evaluating as a statement or as an expression, besides the return value? Or is that the only difference?

Comment: Expressions can produce values; examples are `x - 1`, `foo(blah)`, `lambda x:y`. Statements are usual lines of code in Python, and include things like assignments `x = 1` and function definitions. An expression by itself can be a statement, but not all statements can be treated as expressions. (You can think of an expression as anything you could pass to a function).

Answer (score 2):

Changing `Py_single_input` to `Py_eval_input` seems to resolve both issues.

The former treats the string as part of the interpreter loop, while the latter evaluates a single expression and gives you an object back. (I'm not sure what the return value means in the former case, but it's not the value of the expression.)

EDIT: Just tested it, and as per **nneonneo**'s answer below, the result with `Py_single_input` is indeed `Py_None`.